# How can I defend against Counter?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I've noticed, that some of the enemies I fought possess the [**Counter Skill**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Counter), especially in the Golden Pack DLC.

As a result of this skill, many of my most trusted and powerful allies have come dangerously close to meeting their Maker.

How can I prove to [Morgan](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Morgan_%28Awakening%29), my child, that I am indeed the best Tactician in the world, by not risking the lives of my friends to such a dangerous skill?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Counter Skill is indeed one of the most dangerous skills an enemy can possess, but it does have weaknesses that can be leveraged. Here are four methods I found, that can be used to "*counter a Counter*". The methods are sorted by relevance.

## Snipe

Counter does not work on ranged attacks. It **will** work on magic, if your unit is attacking from an adjacent tile, though. Therefore, the best way to counter Counter, is to attack from afar. Whichever weapon you use to achieve that, does not matter.

## Kill

Counter works only against non-lethal attacks. Meaning: If the enemy has 80 HP, and you deal 80 damage or more, you will not suffer from Counter. Consequently, [**Lethality**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Lethality) is your best skill against Counter, albeit somewhat risky to use, since there is no way to predict its activation (unless by abusing the RNG).
**Be extra careful** against enemies who also possess the skill: [**Miracle**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Miracle) or [**Pavise**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Shield) or [**Aegis**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Aegis) or any other skill that may reduce the amount of damage received.
It is also recommended to avoid using this method with units, that have the [**Astra skill**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Astra_%28Skill%29), as Astra halves the damage done and thus maximizes the damage received from Counter (the [**Astra bow**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Astra_%28weapon%29) is fine though, as it is a ranged weapon).

## Recover

This method relies on the use of recovery, in order to offset the terror that is the Counter skill. Obviously, having a good healer in the back is going to help a lot against Counters, but that is only if you manage to survive it. Also, when fighting many Counter users, you'll need either many healers, or a healer with [**Fortify**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Fortify) or the [**Goddess Staff**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Goddess_Staff).
Alternatively, you may offset the damage received from a Counter with the skills: [**Sol**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Sol_(Skill)), [**Aether**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Aether) or [**Lifetaker**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Lifetaker) (though Lifetaker is useful only during your own turn). Alternatively to the Sol skill, there's also the [**Sol sword**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Sol_(weapon)).
[**Nosferatu**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Nosferatu) and [**Aversa's Night**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Aversa%27s_Night) are especially useful against Counter, as they can not only be used to snipe, but also to recover some of the health lost on Counter, as the healing effect of those weapons is guaranteed to activate.

## Support

Counter doesn't work against Dual Attacks, so one of the safest ways to defeat an enemy who Counters, is to attack him with a unit, that does little to no damage and who is being supported by a unit that does a lot of damage. Both units preferably have a high support level with each other, in order to increase the odds of launching the "Dual" Attack.
This is likely the least relevant method to use, as most characters that could survive fighting a Counter user, will also have a high enough Str/Mag to deal significant damage, even when equipping the weakest weapons available. Also, the amount of units that can make use of this method, is going to steadily decrease, as your units grow stronger.

Comment: sniping is by far the best solution to counters, especially with long range magic.

Comment: @spartacus Yes, that is why it is listed on top ;-)

Comment: Also, don't use Astra if you plan to kill them to avoid Counter, and watch out for Aegis and Pavise.

Comment: @Brian Yes, the `Be extra careful against enemies who also possess the skill: Miracle or Pavise or Aegis` pretty much cover this. The tip about Astra is a good one, though. But I don't think people will want to unequip Astra, just because some enemy units have counter.

Comment: @Nolonar True, but one time I set up Say'ri to kill one of the Entombed who have counter. She had a 100% hit chance and would hit twice, each for more than half of its (and her) health. I figured she would be fine, but she decided to use Astra on the second attack. After a lot of me yelling "No no no!" at her, she killed it with 1 hp left. Not sure how I forgot about Miracle, because something similar happened to me a few times because of it. It's best to avoid the kill method if you have Astra of they have Miracle.

Comment: @Brian I have edited my answer, to add a warning concerning Astra and the Kill method. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do note that Miracle means counter will reflect *all* of the overkill damage -- which means you'll get hit for 99 if you activated lethality, and your opponent activated miracle.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever have they money or get your hands on a high crit spell or weapon like the Sol Katti, Killing weapons, Ruin tomb and others with around 45% crit.
Set up a character with a high skill stat and crit skills like Wrath, Zeal, Focus(If alone), and Gamble (Limit breaker if you can) Pair up with somebody who gives a lot of skill with Anathema, support+ and a high Relationship rank. Crits triple damage, if you get this set up right you can reach a max of 150 crit with wrath active, while the max luck you could get is around 70ish with the Serpent bow equipped and limit breaker.

Comment: If the opponent happens to have a ton of luck, miracle and counter, you are best using a ranged weapon. Skills like Luna or Ignis also boost the crits so it renders Pavise and Aegis basically useless when you deal crits.